# SubDomains for blogs

Tags: seo, blogs, subdomain

Am I creating competitors for my site by creating subdoamins... becos Google treats subdomains as individual domains... so, am I going to create/build competitors for my website....

I want to go for subdomains.. please explain me the drawbacks and at the same time advantages of having subdomains...

One more question... subfolders are mostly used for blogs... but why the wordpress, blogspot has taken subdomains like if I create any blog then in wordpress it would appear like http://www.health.wordpress.com... so why it has taken subdomain...???

Answer (score 2):

> Am I creating competitors for my site
>   by creating subdoamins

It doesnt matter if it is subdomain or main domain. Unless you have very good content and good hits you are not creating a competition.

> but why the wordpress, blogspot has
>   taken subdomains like if I create any
>   blog then in wordpress it would appear
>   like
>   http://www.health.wordpress.com... so
>   why it has taken subdomain...???

Its just their way of implementation. BTW this is not programming realted. So voted to close.